# different keys with AVL trees

Tags: c++, oop

In my homework i was given this C style struct:

```
typedef struct {
    int x, y;
} Point;
```

I have 2 AVL trees. the values on the first should be sorted first by X location, then by Y, and in the second tree, first by Y then by X.

my C++ is a bit rusty so i want to know if i figured it right:

since i have 2 forms of sort, i should have 2 extra classes that will be used as keys for the AVL trees: each will be based on the Point type, and will have assignment operator overloaded to be able to convert from the key type to the Point type.

the reason i want to use two classes is to overload the "<" operator for each one of them, so i wont have to have some odd `compareByX(Point p)` function.

pseudocode for the AVL trees declaration:

```
AVLTree< XthenY, Value > firstTree;
AVLTree< YthenX, Value > secondTree;
```

is this a reasonable thing to do?

i hope my question was clear enough

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The C++ standard library handles this by a template argument that should be a function or functional:

```
struct XthenY
{
    bool operator()(Point const &a, Point const &b) const
    {
        // comparison logic
    }
};
```

See, e.g., the `strcmp` example in the [original STL docs for `map`](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/Map.html).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. the problem is that in the assignment we are not allowed to manipulate the Point struct

Comment: @bks: this option doesn't need a modification to `struct Point`.

Comment: we can't use STL in our assignments, sorry i didn't write it before

Comment: @bks: you don't need the STL. I'm just recommending tackling the problem the way the STL does. (If you could use it, you'd just skip the AVL tree altogether.)

Comment: I think i'm starting to understand. about the comparison logic, i read that `strcmp` returns a value greater than 0 if the two strings are equal and other values according to the relation between the two strings. now, the operator you gave me returns `bool`. am i missing something here?

Comment: @bks: you're wrong about `strcmp`, but that's immaterial. The idea is that you have a function object that returns `true` is `a` is less than `b`.

Comment: so just to see if i understand: if i implement the `operator()` function inside the struct, and have `XthenY p1, p2;` initialized with values, will `p1 < p2` return `true` if `p1` is indeed smaller than `p2`?

Comment: @bks: Yes. The comparison logic is pretty simple.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5742/discussion-between-bks-and-larsmans)